# .NET Entity Framework. Find proxy within context using actual object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am sending entities over WCF after I get an object from a context's proxy.
On another client that receives this entity as an object. I would like to look in its context if there already is a proxy for that entity.

I can't find any question on this, and I was wondering if anyone has done something similar?

Comment: Please elaborate. You do realise this is not remoting, that is, the object you receive on the client has no relation whatsoever to the object living in the server?

Comment: You need to chekc that on the client side or server side? Client side you don't have the DbContext. But on server side you can detect that.

Comment: I want clients to send eachother modified entities. If a client receives an entity. I want it to update its context with a fresh copy of that entity from the database (reload.) If it does not exist in the context I want to add it.

Comment: I did not realise that its not remoting. But I'm using find() to find the entity within my context.

Comment: From your last comment, looks like you are seeking for `Find` method. It returns the tracked entity instance (proxy or not) with the same PK if it's tracked, or will try load and return it from the database. If you want to seek just the tracked instances, you can use `DbSet.Local` property.

Comment: Why do you want to update a *context*? That suggests you have long-lived context instances hanging around, which is a major anti-pattern.

Comment: The reason I have a long-lived context is because of my context size. Its an entire database. Don't want to repull all that data each time.

Comment: Really? Then don't expect any database interaction (`ReLoad`, `SaveChanges`, ...) to perform decently.